# Property 'remoteJoin' does not exist on type 'Adapter'

Tags: typescript, redis, node-redis

I am trying to use @socket.io/redis-adapter with my express/Typescript app and I am following the [documentation](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-redis-adapter#redisadapterremotejoinidstring-roomstring) for it but I can't get it to work.

I have this line exactly as in the documentation: `io.of("/").adapter.remoteJoin(socketID, roomName)` but I get the error `Property 'remoteJoin' does not exist on type 'Adapter'`.

I tried to do:

```
const adapter = io.of("/").adapter;
```

In this case, "adapter" is of type: "Adapter", but I think it needs to be of type "RedisAdapter" so I can have access to the `remoteJoin` method

What am I doing wrong?